# Cannot find module 'vue/complier-sfc'

Tags: jhipster

I try to upgrade our project to the JHipster latest 7.6.0. I get an error

```
Cannot find module 'vue/complier-sfc'
```

after fixing an upstream dependency conflict on @vue/eslint-config-prettier.

I am not sure whether it is caused by my operation error or not.

Comment: Can you please enter this as an issue in the JHipster project with steps to reproduce? https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues

Comment: Ok, I will do so.